# I'm having problems Displaying HTML response data in the browser with Node JS

Tags: node.js, serverside-javascript

So I'm requesting information from a schools web application that displays course listings. Everything works fine because I can output the HTML response to the console or Write the HTML response to an HTML file. But What I would like to do is to display the response on the browser directly. Thanks in advance for your assistance. My code below:

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var http = require('http');

var postData = querystring.stringify({
    "semester": "20161Summer 2015",
    "courseid": "",
    "subject": "IT  INFORMATION TECHNOLOGY",
    "college": "",
    "campus": "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,A,B,C,I,L,M,N,P,Q,R,S,T,W,U,V,X,Y,Z",
    "courselevel": "",
    "coursenum": "",
    "startTime": "0600",
    "endTime": "2359",
    "days": "ALL",
    "All": "All Sections"
});

var options = {
    hostname: 'www3.mnsu.edu',
    port: 80,
    path: '/courses/selectform.asp',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': postData.length
    }
};

http.createServer(function(request, response){  

var req = http.request(options, function(res){
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);//Here I can display the response on the console.
        res.write(chunk);//Here I want to display the response on the browser but I get an error.
    });

    res.on('end', function(){
        console.log('END OF TRANSFER');
    });
});

req.on('error', function(e){
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write(postData);
req.end();
}).listen(8000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `on('data')` event callback you are writing using the wrong response object.

You should set the content type of the browser response, write the chunks of data coming from the external page and, when data is finished, close the browser response. Like this:

```
http.createServer(function(browserRequest, browserResponse) {
    //Set the content type header of the response sent to the browser
    browserResponse.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });

    // Creating the request executed by the server
    var serverRequest = http.request(options, function(serverResponse) {
        serverResponse.setEncoding('utf8');
        serverResponse.on('data', function(chunk) {
            // Sending data to the browser
            browserResponse.write(chunk);
        });

        serverResponse.on('end', function() {
            // Closing browser response
            browserResponse.end();
        });
    });

    serverRequest.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });

    serverRequest.write(postData);
    serverRequest.end();
}).listen(8000);
```